# CasperJS - access JS property

Tags: testing, phantomjs, casperjs

I want to test that the value of `mns.core` is set in CasperJS. I have tried the following:

```
casper.test.begin('Upholstery contains stuff', 3, function (test) {
    casper.start('http://127.0.0.1/layouts/en_gb/page-upholstery.php', function () {
        var mns = this.evaluate(function(){
            return mns;
        });
        console.log(typeof mns.core);
        test.assert(typeof mns.core == "object","mns has properties");
    });



    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

`mns` is set as an object in casperJS, and when loaded via a browser `mns.core` is an object, however it fails this test, as it's showing as undefined.

Comment: Maybe you could use the utils module directly in Casper : [Casper Utils](http://casperjs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/utils.html) , there are some useful functions as `isType()`, `isObject()`, etc...

Comment: Thanks, Casper Utils looks like it'll come in handy but the below fixed my problem as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, I think it's easier to use `test.assertEval()` than `this.evaluate() + another test.assert`, it does the same, so :

```
this.test.assertEval(function() {
    return typeof mns.core === 'object';
    },"mns has properties");
```

Comment: I don't know why this worked above my method as it's just a shorthand approach, but it worked, so all is good.

Comment: Yes it's strange, for me it should work as well, you can pass back an object from DOM context to casper context (the problem is here), so I don't see why it's undefined, what do you have with `console.log(JSON.stringify(mns,4,'\t');` ? Nothing too normally.

Comment: `mns` is an object in the page. If I load the page in a browser, and type `mns.core` into console, it returns all the properties. However; on the page, if I do `mns.swatch` I get a result, in CasperJS I get undefined. It is loaded via  dependency injector though - could this be it?

Comment: I used `.waitForResource`and it now works ok :) thank you again Fanch for your help

Comment: So that was that ! You're welcome. Though I don't see why it worked with assertEval(), if the resource wasn't loaded :p Maybe a random fail.